# udf using class method pyspark

Tags: class, pyspark, user-defined-functions

My problem: How can i call a function inside another function in a class using pyspark  udf.
I am trying to write a pyspark udf using a method from a class called Anomalie in the file devAM_hive.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import re
class Anomalie():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Anomalie_udf = F.udf(Anomalie.aux,ArrayType(StringType()))
    def aux(texte):
        code_utilisateur=re.findall(r'[\s]*\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}[\s]*\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}\s(\w?\.?\s?.*)\s\(', texte)
        return code_utilisateur
    def auto_test(self,df):
        df=df.withColumn("name",self.Anomalie_udf(F.col("Description")))
        return df
```

When i call this from the main file. I am getting an error named " No module named 'devAM_hive'".But my module in which I defined the class is imported.

```
from devAM_hive import *
A=Anomalie()
df=A.auto_test(row_data)
df.select("name").show(50)
```

The error message:

```
22/04/09 14:30:58 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 588, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 447, in read_udfs
    udfs.append(read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf, udf_index=i))
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 249, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 160, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 430, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'devAM_hive'
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i call this from the main file. I am getting an error named " No module named 'devAM_hive'". But my module in which I defined the class is imported.

Importing works because you were importing it from the **driver** where it's available (sitting next to your main file). But running won't work because your **executors** don't have it. So what you wanted to do is [distributing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#bundling-your-applications-dependencies) that class using `--py-files`. By doing that, the class will be in executor's classpath.

```
spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName('Test App')
    .config('spark.submit.pyFiles', '/path/to/devAM_hive.py')
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

Comment: can you explain more please @pltc

Comment: How exactly did you run your spark application with your main file?

Comment: I have a linux machine. To run my program I activate my environment then I call the main: python path/main.py. 
I don't use spark-submit

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: I have the same pbm